# Error while installing Poster (Python Module)

Tags: python, post, http-post, httppostedfile, http-post-vars

I'm trying to install [Chris Atlee's python Poster library](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/) so I can upload a file using a HTTP POST query from within my script.

On python 2.3, when I type `# python setup.py install`, I get the following error. The install continues, but I can't `>>> import poster` later on.

```
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poster/encode.py to encode.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poster/encode.py", line 112
    @classmethod
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poster/streaminghttp.py to streaminghttp.pyc
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poster/streaminghttp.py", line 114
    newheaders = dict((k,v) for k,v in req.headers.items()
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
byte-compiling build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/poster/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.3 didn't have support for decorators (that's what @classmethod is) or list comprehensions (which is the second error), so you're either going to have to find an older version of Poster, or stick with urllib/urllib2 for doing your HTTP work.

Actually, it looks like Poster was created around July, 2008, so there's unlikely to be a version that supports Python 2.3 even if you could find the original source.  Any particular reason you can't upgrade to the latest Python 2.x at least?